# Jest with redux store reset causes RTK warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, rtk-query

When running jest tests, I was aiming to use my actual redux store for the tests.
I am using `RTK Query` to handle interacting with an outside API.  The API is being mocked via `msw`.

I found that I have to reset the store between each test so the results are not persisted across tests.  So I've added a `RESET` action to the store solely for testing purposes.

---

Everything works as expected. however I'm seeing a warning in the jest logs that states:

```
Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "api" has not been added to the store.
Features like automatic cache collection, automatic refetching etc. will not be available.
```

This only is shown if I interact with an RTK endpoint.  I have a feeling it's because I need to re-initialize or restart the RTK cache or something when I `RESET`.

I'm very unsure what to do as things seem to be working as intended as far as testing goes.

---

Here is the **store**:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore, AnyAction, Reducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { FLUSH, PAUSE, PERSIST, persistReducer, persistStore, PURGE, REGISTER, REHYDRATE } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import { myApi } from "@/store/rtk/myApi";
import authSlice from "@/store/slices/authSlice";
import appSlice from "@/store/slices/appSlice";
import paginationSlice from "@/store/slices/paginationSlice";
import modalSlice from "@/store/slices/modalSlice";
import filesSlice from "@/store/slices/filesSlice";

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    [myApi.reducerPath]: myApi.reducer,
    app: appSlice,
    auth: authSlice,
    pagination: paginationSlice,
    modal: modalSlice,
    files: filesSlice,
});

// Create a rootReducer which will have additional actions.  In this case, "RESET" the entire store.
const rootReducer: Reducer = (state: RootState, action: AnyAction) => {
    if (action.type === "RESET") {
        storage.removeItem("persist:auth");

        // state = undefined;
        state = {} as RootState;
    }

    return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

const persistConfig = {
    key: "myapp",
    blacklist: [myApi.reducerPath, "app", "pagination", "modal", "files"],
    storage,
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer),
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        }).concat([myApi.middleware]),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>;

// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most "clean" way would be not to reuse your redux store, but to create a new instance of your store for each test. That's what we do in the RTK Query sources.

If for some reason, you cannot do that, use your reset action to reset all slices but the api slice - and then do a `dispatch(api.utils.resetApiState())` for the api.

Comment: I saw a lot of examples of people creating new store instances between tests, but it seemed as if the stores were not created exactly as they would in the actual app.  Hence I was trying to use the exact same store as my app is.
Is there a minimal example of creating new store instances between tests laying around somewhere?  The magic seems to happen in `setupApiStore`, but man there's a lot going on in there haha.  Thank you for your help tho!! I appreciate it.

Comment: Until I get my head wrapped around properly re-creating my store, `dispatch(api.util.resetApiState())` worked as described.  Thank you.

Comment: You'd move your logic ()configureStore call etc) into your own `makeStore` function so your normal store would end up as `export const store = makeStore()` - and then you'd also use that `makeStore` function in your test setup

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience <3